# How can I aggregate values over multiple columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got a table that looks like the following:

```
column1 | column2 | column3 | .... | column_n
----------------------------------------------
null    | null    | val     | .... | null
val     | null    | null    | .... | null
null    | val1    | null    | .... | val2
```

I would like to obtain a query-result that aggregates all the values of the different columns. The range of none null values is between 0 and 2, where 1 is the common case and 0 or 2 are edge-cases. The result should look like:

```
column1 | column2 | column3 | .... | column_n | result
-------------------------------------------------------
null    | null    | val     | .... | null     | val
val     | null    | null    | .... | null     | val
null    | val1    | null    | .... | val2     | val1, val2
```

The values are strings. Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CONCAT_WS` function should work here:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(',', column1, column2, column3, ..., column_n) AS result
FROM yourTable;
```

`NULL` values will automatically be removed from the resulting CSV output.

[image]

### Demo

Comment: I obviously didn't realize that you had answered when I answered.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm going to "review" your latest answers now, but I will say here that I _never_ double post on you, or anyone else, if my answer is the same.

Answer (score 1):

To aggregate columns with PostgreSQL, you can use the `||` operator :

```
Select col1 || col2;
```

An other solution, you can use `concat` function, but the `NULL` value are ignored.

If you need separator, you can use `concat_ws` function, "_ws" means "with_separator"

You can found complete information [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)

Answer (score 1):

If the table has a primary key (`id`), you can use jsonb in a generic solution. You do not have to know the number and names of the other columns:

```
drop table if exists my_table;
create table my_table(id int primary key, col1 text, col2 text, col3 text);
insert into my_table values
    (1, 'alfa', null, null),
    (2, null, null, null),
    (3, 'alfa', null, 'beta');

select t.*, string_agg(value, ', ') as result
from my_table t
left join jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t)- 'id') on value is not null
group by id;

 id | col1 | col2 | col3 |   result   
----+------+------+------+------------
  1 | alfa |      |      | alfa
  2 |      |      |      | 
  3 | alfa |      | beta | alfa, beta
(3 rows)
```